# Can i use background-image to any specific <li> from a a whole set of <li>s?

Tags: css

My code is :

```html
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li id="f">Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Our Companies</li>
        <li>Our Projects</li>
        <li>Photo Gallery</li>
        <li>Latest News</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>             

    </ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#menubar ul li#f {
    background-color:#D63030;
    margin-left:70px !important;
    background-image:abc.jpg
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Doesn't your code work?

Comment: Strange. It works here https://jsfiddle.net/g6j364mh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS needs a small tweak:

```
#menubar ul li#f {
    background-color:#D63030;
    margin-left:70px !important;
    background-image: url(abc.jpg)
}
```

`background-image` can take one of 3 different values:

```
background-image: none;
background-image: url(<filepath>);
background-image: inherit
```

The first one says the element has no background image. The second one tells the browser what url to use to find the background image. The third one will inherit the image from the element's parent.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)